# Getting Undefined Index using While statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code

```
$sqlSubscription = "SELECT `user_id` FROM subscriptions WHERE `user_id` = '".$user_id."' and `course_id` = 'calculus_1'";
            $subscriptionResult = mysql_query($sqlSubscription);

            if($subscriptionResult === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // temp error handling
              }


                while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($subscriptionResult))
                    {
                        $user_id = $rows['user_id'];
                        $course_id = $rows['course_id'];
                        if($user_id==1 && $course_id="calculus_1")

                            {

                                //do some work


                            }

                     }
```

I'm getting the error `Notice: Undefined index: course_id` The line that causes the error is in the while statement `$course_id = $rows['course_id'];` The strange part is that I can select from where both user and course ids match, and there aren't any errors doing something simple like an echo, but when I add this while statement to verify that both the user and course_ids match a certain rule before outputting data I get this error.

Here is an export of the PHP Arrays through phpMyAdmin

```
<?php
/**
 * Export to PHP Array plugin for PHPMyAdmin
 * @version 0.2b
 */

//
// Database `test`
//

// `escholars`.`subscriptions`
$subscriptions = array(
  array('user_id' => 'test','course_id' => 'calculus_1','start_date' => '2013-09-12','end_date' => '2013-09-28')
);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not appear to be selecting the `course_id`.

You'll need to select it in order to include it in the result set. Otherwise it will not be included in your fetched array and will be undefined.

Try this:

```
SELECT `user_id`,`course_id` FROM .....
```

Comment: To add on, you can always either define the var before doing the while loop, or turn down the error reporting so it won't show these notices, but making it part of the SQL will be a more permanent fix

Answer (score 2):

To compare you need == signs

```
if($user_id==1 && $course_id=="calculus_1")
```

And you are selecting something WHERE course_id="something" so you don't need to return the same value from database $rows['course_id']

```
$course_id = "calculus_1";
```

Comment: in the case that i need to verify that two values are met, for example user_id = test and course_id = calculus, how would i setup that if statement using the while loop that i have?

Comment: That's a good point, Sbml. The `course_id` is hardcoded in the query. So, in this context, no need to fetch it back out again.